# Extra move constructions on custom allocator for clang

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, clang++, allocator

I am trying to write a custom allocator for vector. This is the skelton code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Noisy
{
   Noisy() { std::cout << "Default ctor called" << '\n'; }
   Noisy(const Noisy&) { std::cout << "Copy ctor called" << '\n'; }
   Noisy& operator=(const Noisy&) { std::cout << "Copy assignment called" << '\n'; return *this; }

   Noisy(Noisy&&) { std::cout << "Move ctor called" << '\n'; }
   Noisy& operator=(Noisy&&) { std::cout << "Move assignment called" << '\n'; return *this; }
};

template <typename T>
struct StackAllocator : Noisy
{
   using value_type = T;
   T* allocate(std::size_t n) { return nullptr; }
   void deallocate(T* p, std::size_t n) {  }
};

int main()
{
   using alloc_t = StackAllocator<int>;
   auto alloc = alloc_t{};
   std::vector<int, alloc_t> vec(alloc);
}
```

On gcc 6.3, this produces what I expected: ([Online link](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Am9AtF4zzu0tlQz1))

```
Default ctor called
Copy ctor called
```

However, on clang 3.9, this produces: ([Online link](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/g3YWMJEoSK6oQn30))

```
Default ctor called
Copy ctor called
Move ctor called
Move ctor called
```

This is the source code of clang vector implementation. ([here](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/vector)), but I couldn't find anything that would explain the two extra move constructions. (Interestingly I discovered that it uses compressed pair to take advantage of EBO for empty allocators)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tldr; If you just follow the calls, the copy and two moves come from:

1. Copy into the `__compressed_pair` constructor
2. Move into the `__libcpp_compressed_pair_imp` constructor
3. Move into the `__second_` member

---

You call [`vector(allocator_type const&)`](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/vector#L482):

```
    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY explicit vector(const allocator_type& __a)
#if _LIBCPP_STD_VER <= 14
        _NOEXCEPT_(is_nothrow_copy_constructible<allocator_type>::value)
#else
        _NOEXCEPT
#endif
        : __base(__a)
    {
#if _LIBCPP_DEBUG_LEVEL >= 2
        __get_db()->__insert_c(this);
#endif
    }
```

which calls [`__vector_base(allocator_type const&)`](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/vector#L432):

```
template <class _Tp, class _Allocator>
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
__vector_base<_Tp, _Allocator>::__vector_base(const allocator_type& __a)
    : __begin_(nullptr),
      __end_(nullptr),
      __end_cap_(nullptr, __a)
{
}
```

where `__end_cap_` is a [`__compressed_pair<pointer, allocator_type>`](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/vector#L339), where we invoke the constructor [`__compressed_pair(pointer, allocator_type)`](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/b4d17ade8956ef2c77cbb6e7cd9461edd1f58bca/include/memory#L2322):

```
_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY __compressed_pair(_T1_param __t1, _T2_param __t2)
    : base(_VSTD::forward<_T1_param>(__t1), _VSTD::forward<_T2_param>(__t2)) {}
```

Now, neither of our types are the same and neither are empty or final, so the base constructor that we invoke is [`__libcpp_compressed_pair_imp<pointer, allocator_type, 0>(pointer, allocator_type)`](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/b4d17ade8956ef2c77cbb6e7cd9461edd1f58bca/include/memory#L2106):

```
_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY __libcpp_compressed_pair_imp(_T1_param __t1, _T2_param __t2)
    : __first_(_VSTD::forward<_T1_param>(__t1)), __second_(_VSTD::forward<_T2_param>(__t2)) {}
```

Comment: shit! I had stopped at compressed pair, at which point I had started looking at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/utility/doc/html/compressed_pair.html. Thanks! that explains two extra move constructions. Although could you explain this comment 
"Now, neither of our types are the same and neither are empty or final, so the base constructor that we invoke is"

Comment: @skgbanga The "compressed" of `compressed_pair` suggests that it is slightly more complicated than just two members right? In this case, there's nothing we can compress.